# ON DUPLICATE KEY syntax issue

Tags: mysql

I am updating 250 products from 'tmp' table into 'products' table

```
INSERT INTO products (EAN, brand, productname) 
SELECT column03, column07, column04 FROM tmp 
WHERE column03 NOT IN (SELECT EAN FROM products) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE productname = 'test'
```

This works perfectly fine, but one would expect when running the query again, productname in 'products' should be updated to test for all rows. But strangely only one row seems to be updated.

EAN is unique column, and in between the queries, no changes are made to neither 'tmp' nor 'products'. So the values in products.EAN varchar(200) are exactly the same as in tmp.column03 varchar(200). Yet still it seems it is not identified as duplicate key.

Comment: Can you provide sample data, and the table structure?

Comment: Because `WHERE column03 NOT IN (SELECT EAN FROM products)`

Comment: You just created a whole new set of EAN's in `products` so now all rows in `tmp` will have a matching EAN in `products`

Comment: You see no duplicates because if there are any this `WHERE column03 NOT IN (SELECT EAN FROM products)` stops them from being inserted

Comment: Sometimes the answer is right in front of you, but you cannot see it :) 

Previously I used the WHERE clause because unique values gave me some errors. Now i removed the where clause and it works as expected. Thanks guys!